# Find the area of the region bounded by: $r^2=50\cos(2\theta)$

Tags: calculus, area

How can I do this? I can do Find the area inside one leaf of the rose: $r=\sin(6\theta)$ but cannot figure this one out.

Please I need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rough picture is very useful. There is curve for $\theta=0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$.  Then since $r^2$ cannot be negative, there is no curve from $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Then there is curve from $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}$ to $\theta=\pi$,and there is still curve from $\theta=\pi$ to $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{4}$, then no curve for a while, then curve from $\theta=\frac{7\pi}{4}$ to $2\pi$.

That gives a flower with two petals. The easiest way to compute the area  is probably to think of the flower as made up of $4$ parts identical to the part between $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$. The total area is
$$4\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{2}(50) \cos(2\theta)\,d\theta.$$

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct answer? I have worked it out and gotten a different one, but neither seem to be correct.

Comment: What did you get and what is said to be the correct answer?

Comment: I do not know the correct answer, but I got 620pi rather 625, but that may be miss calculations on my part.

Comment: A quick calculation gives me $625\pi$.

Comment: yeah, this is for my math homework, and it says that it is wrong iguess

Comment: I scr--ed up, it says $r^2=50\cos(2\theta)$, and we want to integrate $\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\theta)\,d\theta$, then multiply by $4$.  So no squaring, it has already been squared. I think we get $50$.

Comment: You are welcome. When looking at it, I got fooled by the $r^2$, since "normally" our curve is given as $r=f(\theta)$.